# Relation between image on retina and the real one: looking at the two objects that are 45 degrees apart, what's the distance in the actual image?

Tags: neuroscience, human-eye, light, optics

These are what I understand about the vision.

[image]

1. lights come through the pupil.
2. an inverted image of the real objects is formed on the retina. which is determined by the angles.
   (so (a, d) and (b, c) look the same)
3. the retinal image is tiny(about 3~5cm?) and inverted.
4. our vision is somehow flipped and magnified version of the image on retina.

My question is: what's the relation between the actual angle on the objects and the distance appeared in the real vision. As shown above, what's the distance between two objects which are 45 degrees apart? On the retina, we can calculate the distance between the image of the two dots which are 45 degrees apart(for example, the image formed by a and c), but how do we know the distance between two dots on the real vision?

In short: What's the magnification rate? between the two(image on the retina and the actual vision)?

Comment: Usually we measure that distance on the retina just in terms of "degrees". For the rest of your question I think you actually just want to read about depth cues, specifically monocular depth cues. There are some existing questions here on that.

Comment: On your sketch, draw also the other eye next to the existing one, and repeat the drawing of light rays and image on the retina. This will help you understand how we can reason about depth and distance between objects.